# how to use find command in adb shell

Tags: android, batch-file, adb, toybox

I want to check if there is a certain file inside a directory in my android device.

I use the following line in my windows batch

```
adb shell find /mnt/sdcard/koinoxrista -name Bill.txt
```

I want to do something if the file exists and something else if file does not exist.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

Find command is not supported in adb shell.
This command will also show you hidden files `adb shell ls -laR | grep filename`

Comment: This won't give you the file path, it will only reports if it exists. To get the path I would instruct grep to also report every directory crawled by `ls`, like this: `adb shell ls -laR | grep -E "filename|:$"`

Comment: @volpato, I've tried to use your suggestion, but still I can't get full path

Answer (score 2):

The `find` command is supported in Android since version 6.0 (Mashmallow).

This is because it's including Toybox since then.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toybox

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the Android emulator does not provide with the 'find' program.

Comment: This is entirely true - android does not ship find, and only recently (possibly after this writing) started shipping grep, so why downvote it?

Answer (score 1):

When you know the exact file name you do not need to use any extra commands like `find` to look for it. Simply check if it exists using built-in shell facilities:

```
adb shell "[ -f /mnt/sdcard/koinoxrista/Bill.txt ] && echo 'found'"
```

Comment: I installed BusyBox, where do I get the find applet ?