# how to check if a file exist using adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have a bash script which goes as follows

```
if [ -f "/sdcard/testfile"]
then 
echo "exists" > /sdcard/outfile
else
echo "does not exist" > /sdcard/outfile
fi
```

I have sufficient permission to run this with `/system/bin/sh`.
I am calling this script from my application and running this with `/system/bin/sh`.
But after running I am getting false, even if the file '/sdcard/testfile' is there.
When I am explicitly running in adb shell, I am getting this error

```
[: not found
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this task? I cannot just use java.io.File because of permission issue of application; therefore, I am adhering to shell script (command).

I need the output in the application itself. I mean,

```
if(filesAreAvailable)
    executeSomething();
else
    executeSomethingElse();
```

Basically I am programmatically writing this script in the `/data/data/myPackageName/files` directory and for calling the command:

```
if [ -f "/sdcard/testfile"]
```

as

```
fileWriterScript.write("if [ -f \"/sdcard/testfile\" ]\n")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13095854/1778421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using another answer posted in stackoverflow. Reference 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6364244/2031060

Answer (score 7):

When using `test`, you need a space after the opening bracket and before the closing bracket.

From `man test`:

```
SYNOPSIS
    test expression
    [ expression ]
```

So change:

```
[ -f "/sdcard/testfile"]
```

to:

```
[ -f "/sdcard/testfile" ]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to use this in bash script then you can do it that way:

```
if [[ `adb shell ls /sdcard/path/to/your.file 2> /dev/null` ]]; then
    echo "File exists";
else
    echo "File doesn't exist";
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do a ls  and then check the output - when it contains "No such file or directory" - the file is not there. But still IMHO you need the permission

Answer (score 1):

I used this script. It's checking if a file exist on the phone.

```
#!/bin/bash

RESULT=$(adb shell "[ -f $1 ] || echo 1")

if [ -z "$RESULT" ]; then
    echo "File exists!"
else
    echo "File not found!"
fi
```